# Yii CActiveDataProvider MANY::MANY

Tags: php, yii

i got 2 models: Project and Users connected with (User.php):

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
            "projects"=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Project','projects_users(user_id, project_id)'),
    );
}
```

I want to show all users in CActiveDataProvider who are **not** connected with project. How can i do it?

Comment: There's a lot of examples on the net how to do that. Take a look here for example: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12637-please-explain-how-to-do-many-to-many-relationships-for-newcomer/

Comment: I cant find any solution there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

foreach($model->users as $cur) {
    $criteria->addCondition("ID != ".$cur->ID);
    }

$users=User::model()->findAll($criteria);

$dataProvider2=new CActiveDataProvider('User');
$dataProvider2->data = $users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$users = User::model()->with('projects')->findAll(array(
    'together' => true,
    'condition' => 'projects.id IS NULL',
));
```